# How to concatenate 3 tables MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In a single database, I have three tables as below:

[image]

I want to concatenate them in some single table, any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by *concatenate* ? You can concatenate two strings - but not multiple tables.... define what you expect as the output from this !

Comment: Do you want to create one table with all the values? Do you want to match the various proposalids and return a dataset with all the available values for every one of them? We will need you to be more detailed with your question. Try giving us an expected output.

Comment: Just want to combine them in one single table without caring proposal ID match or not.In final table we can use proposalid_1,proposalid_2,proposalid_2. and wherever no of rows are not same we can use NULL.

Comment: I am going to try by creating one new table with all rows and will insert them one by one.so in final result all the fields will be in same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help the issue has been solved.

```
SELECT mtlreq.proposalid, mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_taskgrp,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_taskcode,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_itemcode,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_rateper,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_qty,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_Inter_MaterCost,mtlreq.prp_mtlreq_UOM,mtlreq.item_short_desc, resreq.proposalid,resreq.prp_resreq_taskcode ,resreq.prp_resreq_resource,resreq.prp_resreq_usage,resreq.prp_resreq_uom,resreq.prp_resreq_rate,resreq.prp_resreq_overhd_pers
FROM (
   SELECT proposalid,prp_mtlreq_taskgrp,prp_mtlreq_taskcode,prp_mtlreq_itemcode,prp_mtlreq_rateper,prp_mtlreq_qty,prp_mtlreq_Inter_MaterCost,prp_mtlreq_UOM,item_short_desc,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY proposalid) AS rn
   FROM prjdet_prp_taskwork_mtlreq  ) AS mtlreq
FULL OUTER JOIN  (
   SELECT proposalid,prp_resreq_taskcode ,prp_resreq_resource,prp_resreq_usage,prp_resreq_uom,prp_resreq_rate,prp_resreq_overhd_pers,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY proposalid) AS rn
   FROM prjdet_prp_taskwork_resreq) AS resreq
ON mtlreq.rn = resreq.rn
FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT proposalid,mtprp_delv_lineno,mtprp_delv_itemcode,mtprp_delv_cost,mtprp_delv_linelevelmrg,mtprp_delv_proposedamt,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY proposalid) AS rn
   FROM prjproposal_delidtl ) AS delidtl
   on mtlreq.rn = delidtl.rn and resreq.rn=delidtl.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly your answer you want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE COMBINED (/*Insert the set of fields here*/);
GO

INSERT INTO COMBINED
   SELECT  Table1.ProposalId
         , /*all other Table1 fields*/
         ,  Table2.ProposalId
         /*all other Table2 fields*/
         , Table3.ProposalId
         , /*all other Table2 fields*/
   FROM Table1
   FULL JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.ProposalId = Table2.ProposalId
   FULL JOIN Table3 
      ON Table1.ProposalId = Table3.ProposalId;
```

This will match the rows with the same proposal id (but keep the all the its values as proposalid_1,proposalid_2... and for those that do not match will bring the full row and `NULL` for every other fields of the rest of the tables.

Comment: Hi query is combining but repeated values are coming